# Devolver dos valores en Funciones con PLSQL

Tags: funciones, plsql

Estoy intentando que una función de **PLSQL** me devuelva un beneficio de ventas, y a la vez la descripción de un producto.

He conseguido que devuelva el beneficio, que no es mas que utilizar `sum()` con dos tablas.

¿Pero como hago que aparte del beneficio, me retorne la descripción también?

Esta es la **Función**:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION calcularBeneficio(idVenta int) RETURNS double
BEGIN
DECLARE beneficio DOUBLE;
    SELECT SUM(productos.pvp * ventas.cantidad) INTO beneficio 
    FROM ventas, productos 
    WHERE idventa = idVenta AND productos.ID = ventas.IDPRODUCTO;
    RETURN beneficio;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

La idea es pasar como parámetro un ID de una venta, y sacar su beneficio.

Comment: Hola! Como sugerencia, indica siempre para este tipo de preguntas, en qué motor de BD estás trabajando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias crear una funcion que te devuelva una tabla

```
DELIMITER $$
  CREATE FUNCTION calcularBeneficio(idVenta int) RETURNS table(beneficio double, descripcion text)
   BEGIN
   DECLARE beneficio DOUBLE;descripcion TEXT;
   SELECT SUM(productos.pvp * ventas.cantidad), descripcion INTO beneficio, descripcion
   FROM ventas, productos 
WHERE idventa = idVenta AND productos.ID = ventas.IDPRODUCTO;
RETURN next;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

y el resultado lo obtienes con un select * from calcularBeneficio(idVenta)
también podrias usar esta otra forma

```
    DELIMITER $$
      CREATE FUNCTION calcularBeneficio(idVenta int) RETURNS table(beneficio double, descripcion text)
      BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY
         SELECT SUM(productos.pvp * ventas.cantidad), descripcion 
         FROM ventas, productos 
         WHERE idventa = idVenta AND productos.ID = ventas.IDPRODUCTO;
     END;$$
    DELIMITER ;
```